# Event does not reach the parent component from the child

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, computed-properties, emit, vue-props

I send an event to the parent component. When you click the list element, the toggle is handled with the v-model directive. Besides, I need the information on whether the list element is selected to do a v-if render in the parent. I employed emit in the child and both methods and computed props. Both left me with errors. I don't know how to solve this problem.

-Also, I need to share that parent component is rendered before the child although the parent is dependent on the event that comes from the child.

-I am also getting the `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: _vm.updateKumas is not a function"` error message on the console.

-This image also shows the event that comes to the parent component:

[image]

Here is the code

**The Child Component**

```
<template>
  <v-card class="pa-2" height="225" width="150" flat>
    <v-btn disabled block small>Kumaş Tipi</v-btn>
    <v-list dense>
      <v-list-item-group v-model="kumas" color="primary">
        <v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" class="my-list-class">
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title
              v-text="item.text"
              @click="changeKumas"
            ></v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list-item-group>
    </v-list>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    kumas: null,
  }),
  props: ["items"],

  methods: {
    changeKumas() {
      this.$emit("changeKumas", this.kumas);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**The Parent Component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-card>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12">
            <v-row
              align="start"
              justify="start"
              style="height: 300px; width: 1200px"
            >
              <Kumas :items="items" @changeKumas="updateKumas($event)" />
              
            </v-row>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Kumas from "./ListingComponents/Kumas";

export default {
  data: () => ({
    kumas: null,
    items: [
      { text: "İtem1", icon: "mdi-clock" },
      { text: "İtem2", icon: "mdi-account" },
      { text: "İtem3", icon: "mdi-flag" },
      { text: "İtem1", icon: "mdi-clock" },
      { text: "İtem2", icon: "mdi-account" },
      { text: "İtem3", icon: "mdi-flag" },
    ],
  }),
  methods: {
    updateKumas(updatedKumas) {
      console.log(` Kumas in step1 is ${updatedKumas}`);
      this.kumas = updatedKumas;
      console.log(` Kumas in step1 is ${this.kumas}`);
    },
  },
  components: { Kumas },
};
```

Comment: `updateKumas` needs to be in `methods`, not `computed`.

Comment: I tried it and it does not update the kumas prop in the child immediately and it comes one step later.

Comment: You cannot set computed properies like that. If you are trying to set a computed prop you need to use the [getters and setters](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter). And even still you cannot do what you are trying to do there. You set a computed prop like ```computed = value``` not ```computed(value)```. As the other comment states, you need a method not a computed prop.